# Location of standard macOS .keylayouts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, key-binding

I'm trying to make a custom keyboard layout using the Ukelele program by SIL to be installed at `Library/Keyboard Layouts`. I would like to use the standard US keyboard `.keylayout` as a template, does anyone know which directory it's located in?

Comment: Read the manual. That's not your starting point.

Comment: The manual is awful, which is probably why the OP asked this question. In fact, I suspect they did read section 6.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR. What you're probably looking for is `File > New From Current Input Source`, which creates a layout based on your current keyboard (without having to worry about finding `.keylayout` files.

I found this information (somewhat buried) in the tutorial, which is in the Documentation folder of the `.dmg`. There's also a `Resources` folder containing various `.bundle` files which (presumably) contain `.keylayout` files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).